# JSP Session unsual behavior

Tags: java, jsp, session

Before, I normally set and get attributes in session. But lately, one of my session attributes began behaving as if it is null. My team can normally get the specific session attribute using my PC as the host of web application while I myself cannot get. As a short description of my problem, we have the same codes, my team can get values in the session that is run through scriptlets and I cannot. We use tomcat as server, eclipse juno, chrome as browser, and my PC is the only one which encounters this bug. Is there a problem in my machine, browser or some elsewhere?

Code:

```
<% List<Place> places = (List<Place>) session.getAttribute("places");
for (Place p : places ) { %>
    <option value="<%=p.getID()%>"><%=p.getPlaceName()%></option>
<%} %>
```

The `for` loop does execute because as I have said because it does not get a value in the session. I've cleaned my caches and have tried to other browsers but still it behaves like that in my machine...

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the codes, I think it is in the browser or some elsewhere settings...

Comment: do url rewriting and find the session value.

Answer (score 1):

check cookie is enabled in your server not. if cookie is disabled then enable it

Comment: check it in context.xml in tomcat server

Comment: It is allowed, as I have said, my team can normally get values and I cannot

Comment: No. But I can see it enlisted in cookies list of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting session attributes at one place then you should be able to get at other place also. I do not see why It should not.

request.getSession(false);

there can be synchronization issue. always do session work in a synchronize block.

**HttpSessionAttributeListener** can be configured to see when attribute was added to your session.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am puzzling about. All other sessions behave normally, that one is just the problem